# monolog/logger error magento

Tags: magento2, log, psr-logger

can anybody help on this :

> (Psr\Log\InvalidArgumentException): Level "" is not defined, use one
>   of: 100, 200, 250, 300, 400, 500, 550, 600
>   vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php(256):
>   Monolog\Logger::getLevelName(NULL)
>   lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog.php(24):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(NULL, 'Tagalys Request...', Array)

This is how i have used logger

```
protected $logger;
public function __construct(
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
 ) {
     $this->logger = $logger;   
   }

public function xyz(){
$this->logger->log(null, 'Tagalys Request Object: '.json_encode($payload)); 
}
```

I am not getting any log files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` the first parameter must be a level of log.

Different levels can be found under `Psr\Log\LogLevel` :

```
class LogLevel
{
    const EMERGENCY = 'emergency';
    const ALERT = 'alert';
    const CRITICAL = 'critical';
    const ERROR = 'error';
    const WARNING = 'warning';
    const NOTICE = 'notice';
    const INFO = 'info';
    const DEBUG = 'debug';
}
```

So if you want to log for example a debug information you'll have to call:

```
$this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, 'Tagalys Request Object: '.json_encode($payload));
```

To avoid having to specify the level of log, the class provides one method per level so instead of the code above, you can also do:

```
$this->logger->debug('Tagalys Request Object: '.json_encode($payload));
```

The other methods available are:

- `emergency()`
- `alert()`
- `critical()`
- `error()`
- `warning()`
- `notice()`
- `info()`

Using this class you cannot specify a custom log file.

If you want to do so you can use the following code:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylogfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

Comment: Thanks, Raphael, but can i give a custom log file instead of debug.log as follows:    $this->logger->debug('Tagalys Request Object: '.json_encode($payload), null, 'mylogfile.log');

Comment: I get Argument 3 passed to Monolog\Logger::log() must be of the type array, null given

Comment: i tried this too: $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, 'Tagalys Request Object: '.json_encode($payload),'tagalys.log');  i get same error

Comment: @SachinS see my updated answer ;)

Comment: How to pass json_encode($payload) into the $writer

Comment: @SachinS you can do `$logger->info(json_encode($payload))`

Comment: Bro, for multiple logs, can i do this ?                                                                                                                                $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Tagalays_Tag.log');
   $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
   $logger->addWriter($writer);
   $logger->info('Tagalys Request Info: '.json_encode($info));
   $logger->info('Tagalys Response Info: '.$result);

Comment: from 2 different functions different classes same log file

Comment: @SachinS yes u can ;)